# plotting a sliding time window over streaming data

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I receive streaming sensor results around 10 times a second as pairs of points (time,value). i want to continuously plot the last 30 seconds of results (~300 points). i do the following: using animation.FuncAnimation mechanism. whenever the FuncAnimation kicks in i read the latest results from a queue, throws away the oldest results and redraw the plot by using set_data(time_array,value_array). it works well but there's one big con: I have to use set_xlim() every time to make the x axis adjust to the new time values. is there an elegant way around it ? i would like to use relative coordinates where the time axis is [0,30] but cannot find an elegant way to do so. i can always time-shift the all 300 points in the current window so they start at 0 and end at around 30 but this is very inefficient and must be done whenever a new data point is added and an older one discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use

```
ax.autoscale()
```

to scale the axes `ax` to its new content.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a second array that contains only the last 300 points. Something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

fullArray = (time, value)
tempArray = fullArray

while takingData:
    lastTake = (time, value)
    fullArray = np.vstack((fullArray, lastTake))
    try:
        tempArray = np.hstack((fullArray[ -299: ,1 ], lastTake[1]))
    except IndexError:
        tempArray = np.hstack((fullArray[:,1], lastTake[1]))
```

This way you have all of your data saved in `fullArray`, but you also have a 1D array containing only the last 300 points that can be plotted against `range(len(tempData))`
instead of plotting against time.